# Disable some GL_EXTENSIONS for debugging Three.js app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

I want to disable some GL_EXTENSIONS for debugging my Three.js app. One of the users is having trouble that we've pretty much narrowed down to his lack of some extensions. I'd like to be able to reproduce those issues on my development machine so I can implement a workaround for this user. He is important and thousands of miles away.

I have only been able to find programs for viewing current extensions and I have found that using the following code:

```
renderer.context.getExtension('extension_name')
```

will give me some information about the machine. I have not, however, been able to make the extensions which show up in my chrome://gpu become inactive on my end. Specifically, I would like to disable:

```
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
```

I would be happy to disable this system wide on my machine, or within Chrome (our target platform), or even from within the JavaScript. Please let me know if I can provide any further information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot disable an extension but you can choose not to use it. So if you look at the code in build/three.js of release 58 at line 25759 you will see the querying of the `texture_float` extension and at the next line that of `standard_derivatives`. You can set the variable equal to `null` which indicates to three.js that the extension is not supported. Save and run your code with these changes.